# Cómo funciona http.get en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, promesas

Tengo una simple página web cuyo frontend esta en AngularJS y el backend en Laravel.
Al ir a una URL se ejecuta el siguiente código:

```
'use strict';

function FamiliaCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $window, API_CONFIG, $http, $stateParams, $location, ngDialog){
    var user = angular.fromJson($window.multipleStorage().getItem('usuario'));

    $scope.familias = [];

    $scope.error = $rootScope.error;


    function getFamilias(){
        $http.get(API_CONFIG.url + '/familias/listar').then(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status > 199 && response.status < 300) {
                    $scope.familias = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.familias);
                } else {
                    $scope.error.show = true;
                    $scope.error.message = response.data.error;
                }
            }
        );
    }

    let init = function(){
        switch($stateParams.accionFamilia){
            case 'listar':
                
                    getFamilias();
                    console.log($scope.familias);
                break;
            case 'crear':
                console.log('crear');
                break;
        }
    }

    init();
}

angular
  .module('urbanApp')
  .controller('FamiliaCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window', 'API_CONFIG', '$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'ngDialog', FamiliaCtrl]);
```

Yo hago una llamada al servidor para obtener las familias, las cuales muestro en la vista de la siguiente manera:

```
<table class="table table-hover mb0" ng-show="!paginator.loading">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="titulo-table col-md-1" ng-if="isTenant('Contreras')">{{'ID' | translate}}</th>
                                        <th class="titulo-table col-md-8" ng-if="isTenant('Contreras')">{{'Nombre' | translate}}</th>
                                        <th class="titulo-table col-md-3" ng-if="isTenant('Contreras')">{{'Código' | translate}}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr style="cursor: pointer;" class="familia-selection" ng-repeat="familia in familias">
                                        <td  ui-sref="app.familias.detalle({id:familia.id})"  ng-if="isTenant('Contreras')">{{familia.id}}</td>
                                        <td  ui-sref="app.familias.detalle({id:familia.id})" ng-if="isTenant('Contreras')">{{familia.nombre}}</td>
                                        <td  ui-sref="app.familias.detalle({id:familia.id})" ng-if="isTenant('Contreras') && familia.codigo != ''">{{familia.codigo}}</td>
                                        <td  ui-sref="app.familias.detalle({id:familia.id})" ng-if="isTenant('Contreras') && familia.codigo == ''">{{'Sin código'}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Y las familias se ven correctamente.
Mi pregunta es, **por qué el console log de la línea 16 muestra $scope.familias bien pero el segundo console log (línea 41) muestra el array vacío?**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No debería quedarse guardado en el scope el array?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace es un petición como te muestra acá

```js
$http.get(API_CONFIG.url + '/familias/listar')
```

Lo que debes entender es que esto es asincronomo, es decir que va a tomar un tiempo en responder, es por esta razón que al principio la función `init` imprime el valor en blanco pues así está inicialmente `$scope.familias = [];`.

```
    let init = function(){
        switch($stateParams.accionFamilia){
            case 'listar':
                
                    getFamilias();
                    console.log($scope.familias);
                break;
            case 'crear':
                console.log('crear');
                break;
        }
    }

    init();
```

Posteriormente cuando la petición es resuelta imprime el valor dentro del `then`.

```
$http.get(API_CONFIG.url + '/familias/listar').then(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status > 199 && response.status < 300) {
                    $scope.familias = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.familias);
                } else {
                    $scope.error.show = true;
                    $scope.error.message = response.data.error;
                }
            }
        );
```

Y está ingresando en este `if`

```
if (response.status > 199 && response.status < 300) {
    $scope.familias = response.data;
    console.log($scope.familias);// aca ya tienes los datos de tu back
}
```

> Tu petición no esta manejando los errores

Ej:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

De la misma forma tienes otros métodos en [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overview).

```js
$http.get
$http.head
$http.post
$http.put
$http.delete
$http.jsonp
$http.patch
```